# Nodejs empty ReadableStream

Tags: node.js, filestream, fs

I have the following trivial function to copy a file in `nodejs`

```
function copyFileSync(source, target) {
     var readerStream = fs.createReadStream(source);
     var writerStream = fs.createWriteStream(target);
     readerStream.pipe(writerStream);
}
```

`readerStream.length == 0` and I cannot get why, as `source` is an existing, well-formed file. The result is the creation of an empty `target` file. As for debug, I noticed that `data` event is not emitted. I also set file permission to `777`.
Here's a log of the `readerStream` object:

```
{
  "_readableState":{
    "highWaterMark":65536,
    "buffer":[

    ],
    "length":0,
    "pipes":null,
    "pipesCount":0,
    "flowing":false,
    "ended":false,
    "endEmitted":false,
    "reading":false,
    "calledRead":false,
    "sync":true,
    "needReadable":false,
    "emittedReadable":false,
    "readableListening":false,
    "objectMode":false,
    "defaultEncoding":"utf8",
    "ranOut":false,
    "awaitDrain":0,
    "readingMore":false,
    "decoder":null,
    "encoding":null
  } ,
  "readable":true,
  "domain":null,
  "_events":{

  },
  "_maxListeners":10,
  "path":"/my/file/path",
  "fd":null,
  "flags":"r",
  "mode":438,
  "autoClose":true
}
```

Comment: That function is misnamed `copyFileSync`. it is not `Sync`.

Comment: Why do you expect the [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) to have a `.length`?

Comment: @bergi `lenght` is an actual property of the `readerStream` object. You're right, as it's under its `_readableState` property. I'll edit my question. Anyway, this doesn't change the meaning: the stream is empty

Comment: @balanza: No, the meaning is: the stream is *currently* empty. Also, `._readableState` is a private property, which means you shouldn't read to much into it.

Comment: @dan-d this is basically a copy&paste from another stackoverflow question. In fact, I solved my issue just by using `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync`. D'you think my issue is due to this misundertanding?

Comment: @bergi alright, so it seems that's the issue.. well, I'll answer and close this topic soon